# Arzela-Ascoli-like theorem with additional converging term

Tags: functional-analysis, equicontinuity

Let us say that I have a sequence of random $L^p$-valued functions $I^{\varepsilon} \in C([0,T], L^p(\Omega))$ such that

$$\forall_{\varepsilon > 0}\ [[ I^{\epsilon}(t) - I^{\varepsilon}(s) ]]_p \leq (t-s)^{\alpha} + \varepsilon^{\alpha}$$

where $[[ \cdot ]]_p$ is a $L_p$ norm and $\alpha > 0$. Is it possible to say that $(I^{\varepsilon} )_{\varepsilon>0}$ admits a convergent subsequence in this space?

edit: additionally assume that $[[ I^{\varepsilon} ]]_p \leq \sqrt{p} (t^{\alpha} + \varepsilon^{\alpha})$, which is known to correspond to having Gaussian tails, so it is tight $$[[ I^{\varepsilon} 1_{I^{\varepsilon} > y }]]_p \to_{y \to \infty} 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

No. Take $\Omega = \mathbb R$. And define
$$
I^\epsilon(t) = \phi(t + \epsilon^{-1}),
$$
where $\phi$ is supported on $(0,1)$.

To get the desired convergence, you also need compactness in the image space.

Comment: so as I understand for small enough $\varepsilon$ we have $[[ \phi(t + \varepsilon^{-1}) - \phi(s+\varepsilon^{-1}) ]]_p \leq 0$ simply because $t + \varepsilon^{-1}$ falls outside of support range of $\phi$ ?

Comment: No, this would be a consequence of the Hoelder continuity of $\phi$.

Comment: ok, so $\phi$ satisfies $[[ \phi(t) - \phi(s) ]]_p \leq (t-s)^{\beta} $ ? but then we have $[[ I^{\varepsilon}(t) - I^{\varepsilon}(s) ]]_p \leq (t-s)^{\beta}$, not the condition that I wrote, how exactly the additional $\varepsilon^{\beta}$ pops up here? Could you expand on the details a bit? I'm not sure if you meant support in time variable or space variable. Also I added additional assumption on $I^{\varepsilon}$

Comment: $0 \le \epsilon^\beta$ ;) maybe the additional assumption implies convergence, no idea.

Comment: ok, I got confused on some stupid thing then. anyway thanks!